# How to use typedef struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm completely new to C and I'm having trouble with pointers and `typedef struct` structures.

I have two `typedef struct`s defined: `Student` and `Class`, and I am wondering if these are pointers or not:

```
typedef struct _Class {
    char name;
    int grade;
} Class;

typedef struct _Student {
    int number;
    Class *classes;
} Student;

int main() {
    Student **students = (Student**) malloc(100 * sizeof(Student*));
    Student * studentOne;
    (*studentOne).number = 453;
}
```

This is only part of my program but my question is: why we defined the array `students` as double pointers, and `Student *studentOne` as a pointer, but in the `typedef` of `_Student` we have the array `Class *classes` as a single pointer array.

So in my program structure `Student` is a pointer, and structure `Class` is not. Why?

The definition of both `typedef struct` is the same so when to use structure as a pointer?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like for example `_Class`) are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library) in all scopes. You can actually have the same name for both the structure and the type-alias (e.g. `typedef struct Class { ... } Class;`).

Comment: Also note that your example code is very flawed and would not even compile.

Comment: There is a semicolon missting after `typedef struct _Student { int number;   Class *classes; }`

Comment: `Student` is not defined by the code you show.

Comment: "*why we defined the array students as double pointers, and Student *studentOne as a pointer*" this is only known by the person which wrote the code.

Comment: `(*studentOne).number = 453;` is undefined behavior, since you only allocated space for pointers, not actual structs. So, either malloc each actual `Student` separately, or remove the pointer-to-pointer here and just creata an array of structs.

Answer (score 2):

No, the type-alias `Class` (and the others) are *not* pointer types. They are simply aliases for e.g. `struct _Class`.

So instead of (for example)

```
Student * studentOne;
```

you could write

```
struct _Student * studentOne;
```

***If*** you had a type-alias for the `_Student` structure as well!

Answer (score 1):

By your questions it seems to me that you don't really understand pointers and memory allocations so I'll try to explain it simply

Student * studentOne;

Could behave as two things:

1. A simple pointer to a student. Use this option when you want to allocate student on the heap
2. An array of students. For this option you would do something like this:

   Student * studentArr = (Student *)malloc( NUM_OF_STUDENTS *         sizeof(Student))

If you don't want a the student to sit inside the heap you would just have to create a simple student variable

```
Student stud;
```

if you want a student array on the stack it should be created like this

```
Student stud[NUM_OF_STUDENTS]
```

On the counterpart

```
Student ** studentMat;
```

Could behave as two things:

1. An array of pointers to students
2. A student matrix

For option one you would do this:

```
Student ** studentPtrArr = (Student**)malloc(NUM_OF_STUDENTS * sizeof(Student*))
for(int i=0; i < NUM_OF_STUDENTS; i++){
    Student[i] = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student))
}
```

For option two you would do this:

```
Student ** studentPtrArr = (Student**)malloc(NUM_OF_STUDENT_ROWS * sizeof(Student*))
for(int i=0; i < NUM_OF_STUDENTS; i++){
    Student[i] = (Student *)malloc(NUM_OF_STUDENT_COLUMNS sizeof(Student))
}
```

Comment: In C all those casts are useless.

Comment: Also this `NUM_OF_STUDENTS * sizeof(Student)` has to be `NUM_OF_STUDENTS * sizeof(Student*)` or even better `Student ** studentPtrArr = malloc(NUM_OF_STUDENT_ROWS * sizeof *studentPtrArr)`.

Comment: As @alk wrote, you will do yourself a favor if you use the "self referencing" form for `malloc`, i.e. something like `Stuff *ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr)`. This gets the right size each time, regardless of the type of `ptr`.